# Select the same row in two datagridviews

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm using VB in Visual Studio 2010.

I have two datagridviews (dtgStudent and dtgParents). Is it possible for me to select the same row in those two datagridviews?

For example, when I select the first row in "dtgStudent" the first row in "dtgParent" is also selected, as well as if I select the second row on the "dtgStudent" the second row in "dtgparent" is also selected automatically.

If you don't mind, please give me the answer include the coding.

Comment: Show what did you try...show us your code (Use `datagridview.SelectedIndexChanged` event handler)

Comment: Private Sub dtgstudent_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtgstudent.SelectionChanged  
        If dtgstudent.CurrentRow.Selected Then  
            dtgparent.CurrentRow.Selected = True  
        End If  
    End Sub

Comment: Use `e.RowIndex  ` inside of handler

Comment: sorry, can you give me an example about it?
(use e.RowIndex inside of handler)

Comment: Hello Bro, you should not ask a code here without effort..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub dgvStudent_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvStudent.SelectionChanged
    Dim student As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim rowindex As Int32 = student.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    If rowindex >= 0 AndAlso rowindex < Me.dgvParents.Rows.Count Then
        Me.dgvParents.CurrentCell = Me.dgvParents.Rows(rowindex).Cells(0)
        'or instead of column index '0' use a column name(only visible column) 
    End If
End Sub
```